# R - calculating mode and percentages by mode and target

Tags: r, apply, mode

I'm trying to calculate the mode for numeric columns. The columns which are not numeric, should have a "NA" as a placeholder in the vector. I would also need percentages according to a target.  Some example data:

```
c1= c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "C") 
c2= factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2,1,2,1), labels = c("Y","N"))
d= as.Date(c("2015-02-01", "2015-02-03","2015-02-01","2015-02-05", "2015-02-03","2015-02-01", "2015-02-03"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
x= c(1,1,2,3,1,2,4) 
y= c(1,2,2,6,2,3,1) 
t= c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1)
df=data.frame(c1, c2, d, x, y,t) 
df

  c1 c2          d x y t
1  A  Y 2015-02-01 1 1 1
2  B  Y 2015-02-03 1 2 0
3  C  N 2015-02-01 2 2 1
4  C  N 2015-02-05 3 6 1
5  B  Y 2015-02-03 1 2 0
6  C  N 2015-02-01 2 3 0
7  C  Y 2015-02-03 4 1 1
```

I would need the mode for each numeric column:

```
mode=as.numeric(c("NA","NA", "NA", 1,2,1))
mode
[1] NA NA NA  1  2  1
```

and a vector of percentages of rows with t==1, when value in column == mode

```
[1] NA NA NA  0.33  0.33
```

and a vector of percentages of rows with t==1, when value in column != mode

```
[1] NA NA NA  0.75  0.75
```

How could I calculate such vectors?

The best I have found for mode is:

```
library(plyr)

mode_fun <- function(x) {
  mode0 <- names(which.max(table(x)))
  if(is.numeric(x)) return(as.numeric(mode0))
  mode0
}
kdf_mode=apply(kdf,2, numcolwise(mode_fun))
```

But it gives an error if there are any non numeric columns.

Comment: Thanks so much akrun!

Comment: It's so complicated I had to think it through... please see comment under your answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the columns of 'df', apply the `mode_fun` to get the output `vector` ('v1').  We use an `if/else` condition to return `NA` for non-numeric columns.

```
 v1 <- unname(sapply(df, function(x) if(!is.numeric(x)) NA else mode_fun(x)))
 v1
 #[1] NA NA NA  1  2  1
```

For the second case (I guess we don't need the 6th column i.e. 't').  We loop through the columns of 'df' with `sapply`, use the `if/else` condition.  In the `else` condition, we compare whether the `mode` values is equal to the column values (`mode_fun(x)==x)`).   We use the `&` to get the logical index of values that are equal to `mode` that corresponds to `t==1`.  Get the `sum` and divide by the `sum(v1)`.

```
unname(sapply(df[-6], function(x) if(!is.numeric(x)) {
            NA
            } else {
                v1 <- mode_fun(x)==x
                sum(v1 & t==1)/sum(v1) 
  } ))
 #[1]        NA        NA        NA 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

For the third, we change the condition to get the logical index where the column is not equal to the `mode`.  Do the same as in the previous case.

```
unname(sapply(df[-6], function(x) if(!is.numeric(x)){
         NA 
         } else {
              v1 <- mode_fun(x)!=x
              sum(v1 & t==1)/sum(v1)
   } ))
 #[1]   NA   NA   NA 0.75 0.75
```

---

After we calculate 'v1', this can be also done without looping with `sapply`.  We create a logical index where the column `class` is 'numeric' and the column names is not 't' ('indx').

```
indx <- sapply(df, is.numeric) &  names(df)!='t'
```

We subset the 'df' and 'v1' based on 'indx' (`df[indx]`, `v1[indx]`), make the lengths by replicating the `vector` using `col`.  The `col` gives the numeric index of the columns in `df[indx]`.  Then we check whether the subset dataset is equal to the `vector` to give a logical matrix.

```
indx1 <- df[indx]==v1[indx][col(df[indx])]
```

As in the previous code, we use `&` to check whether the `TRUE` values in 'indx1' also corresponds to 't==1`.  Do`colSums`, divide by the`colSums`of 'indx1', and concatenate (`c`) with the`NA` elements of 'v1'

```
unname(c(v1[is.na(v1)], colSums(indx1& t==1)/colSums(indx1)))
#[1]        NA        NA        NA 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Similarly, we can create 'indx2' by changing the condition and then do `colSums` as before

```
indx2 <- df[indx]!=v1[indx][col(df[indx])] 
unname(c(v1[is.na(v1)], colSums(indx2& t==1)/colSums(indx2)))
#[1]   NA   NA   NA 0.75 0.75
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a wrong number in the example, the 0.66 ( v1[4]) was supposed to be 0.33. This is how: The mode is calculated per column (this works now fine!). Then for those cells with value equal to mode we calculate the percentage that have also t==1. For example in column x three values (on rows 1, 2 and 5) are equal to mode (which is 1 for col x), but only in row nr 1 the value in col t is 1 (for rows 2 and 5 t is 0). So this is why the fourth value in v1 should be 1/3=0.33. Similarly for v2 we are looking at values which != mode and how many of them have t==1 and so we get 0.75.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was silent so long because with my real data your code gave only NA:s, although with the example data it worked fine. It took me a while realize that there were NA:s among the number columns preventing the summing. I added sum(mode_fun(x)==x, na.rm=TRUE) and now no problems! Thanks so much!

Comment: @ElinaJ Thanks for the feedback.  The `NA` values sure would create problems.